# pandas.read_csv writes out to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm taking in shipment data from a csv file, I've edited data for privacy purposes, but the thing to look at is when using pandas.read_csv on my csv file the original as shown below is normal in this sense: the ZIP code (01234) has a leading 0, and the order number (22276) is an integer.

After using pandas.read_csv and printing out my data (and viewing my data in a text editor) I see that the leading 0 was taken out from the ZIP code (it is now 1234), and the order number is now a floating number (22276.0)

Original:

> GROUND,THIRD PARTY,Company Name,1 Road
>   Ave,Town,State,01234,,22276,22276,22276,,Customer Name,Street
>   Name,00000 00th Ave
>   Z.Z.,,Town,State,00001,V476V6,18001112222,,,,Package,1

After using pandas.read_csv:

> GROUND,THIRD PARTY,Dreams,100 Higginson
>   Ave,LINCOLN,RI,1234,,22276.0,22276.0,22276.0,,Customer Name,Street
>   Name,00000 00th Ave
>   Z.Z.,,Town,State,00001,V476V6,18001112222,,,,Package,1

I've seen others have these issues as well, and in those questions you will see well-written answers about HOW to fix the problem. What I want to know is WHY the problem exists in the first place. Why does a reading function write out original data back to the file?

**EDIT**

Here's the code I'm currently working with, reference is the name of the column with the order number.

```
import pandas
grid = pandas.read_csv("thirdparty.csv", dtype={'ZIP': int, 'REFERENCE': int})
with pandas.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(grid)
```

Comment: please share the code you are using to read the csv file

Comment: Julian I updated my question!

Comment: To ensure you don't lose the leading 0 in 01234, you need to read ZIP in as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How

You'll want to use the `dtype` argument of `pd.read_csv`. One solution would be to read in all the columns as string type. This will preserve the values exactly as they were in your csv file.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("thirdparty.csv", dtype=str)
```

Though a better solution would be to specify your desired dtype of each column:

```py
data = pd.read_csv(("thirdparty.csv", dtype={‘ZIP’: str, ‘REFERENCE’: int}
```

When writing the csv file back out again you should also use the `float_format` argument to ensure any floats are wrote as you desire.

### Why

You also asked *why* the "problem" exists.

Essentially, when you use `pd.read_csv` without specifying a dtype, anything which looks like a number is read in as a float. So, `01234` is converted to `1234` on read.

When you write back out to your file this number is now wrote as a float. The `pd.read_csv` function **is not** writing out data to the original file.

Comment: jwalton I appreciate your insight. The result was that the program would still write out float values back to the csv file, however throughout the rest of the program the values seem to be treated as int. leading 0's are still being dropped, what I'll do for now is go through the file and handle the data myself but I am interested in Wes McKinney's + co choice to read digits as a float on time of reading. If I find out more, I'll post it here

Comment: Do you use ```pandas.DataFrame.to_csv``` to write the file back out? If so you should use the ```float_format``` argument to ensure any numbers are wrote as you desire.

Comment: In my original program I do not, I currently pulled aside four lines of code, please see my revised question to see what I'm currently working with